# CSS specific classes for day, month and year

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, erb

I have this date_select tag in a HTML page:

```
<%= f.date_select :birthday %>
```

How can I set a specific CSS class for the day, one for the month and another one for the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign css by fragment id.  Assuming your field is returned as 'birthday':

```
#birthday_1i{
  /* year */
}
#birthday_2i{
  /* month */
}
#birthday_3i{
  /* day */
}
```